# Backend Query in marklogic in java API in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to know which query is being run in the backend when we use the Marklogic java api for search keyword or criteria etc.

i could not locate the way to see the query. i tried the enabling the log level to debug but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with looking at the AccessLogs, that should reveal which MarkLogic REST api calls are being made by the MarkLogic Java Client API library. That is well documented, so perhaps sufficient for your needs. I'm not sure it is very useful to drill down even further to look at the actual XQuery code. It would probably require you to poke around in MarkLogic Modules folder to figure out anyhow.

HTH!

Comment: i have already looked at the Access log but did not help much. only have seen the rest api which is being called.

is the any documentation for rest apis which marklogic have like swagger documentation or wadl so atlease i can find out the options .

Comment: No Swagger to my knowledge, but plenty documentation: http://docs.marklogic.com/REST